# AWS code Deployment appspec file how to transfer variables to .sh script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I am tring to use the codeDeployment to deploy my ecr docker file on a EC2 instance. the image tag is dynamically created accoding to github sha. I am really confused how can I get the iamge in.sh script? I try to use environment keyword to pass the variable but failed, the codeDeployment told me the IMG_TAG is null.
there are my github action file, appspec.yml and .sh script

github action yml file

```
name: Deploy to EC2

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main 

jobs:
  build-and-push-image:
    name: Build and Push Docker Image
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ap-southeast-2




      - name: Login to Amazon ECR
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

      - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
        env:
          ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ secrets.ECR_REGISTRY }}
          ECR_REPOSITORY: ${{ secrets.ECR_REPOSITORY }}
          IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
        run: |
          docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
          docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG

      - name: Fill in the new image ID in the AppSpec file
        run: |
          sed -i "s|<PLACEHOLDER_FOR_COMMIT_SHA>|${{ github.sha }}|" appspec.yml
          
      - name: Print the AppSpec file
        run: cat appspec.yml
  deploy-to-ec2:
    name: Deploy to EC2
    needs: build-and-push-image
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ap-southeast-2



      - name: Deploy to EC2 using AWS CodeDeploy
        run: |
          aws deploy create-deployment \
            --application-name cicd \
            --deployment-group-name cicdtest \
            --deployment-config-name CodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime \
            --description "Deploying Docker image to EC2" \
            --github-location repository=$GITHUB_REPOSITORY,commitId=$GITHUB_SHA
        env:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          GITHUB_REPOSITORY: ${{ github.repository }}
          GITHUB_SHA: ${{ github.sha }}
```

appspec.yml

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ec2-user/deployment
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/install_dependencies.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/download_docker_image.sh
      runas: root
      environment:
        - name: IMAGE_TAG
          value: <PLACEHOLDER_FOR_COMMIT_SHA>
      timeout: 300
      
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/start_docker_container.sh
      runas: root
      environment:
        - name: IMAGE_TAG
          value: <PLACEHOLDER_FOR_COMMIT_SHA>
      timeout: 300
      
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: scripts/stop_docker_container.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
```

.sh script

```
#!/bin/bash
# 下载Docker镜像

set -x
AWS_ACCOUNT_ID="161819723243"
REGION="ap-southeast-2"
CONTAINER_NAME="my-app"
IMAGE_REPO_NAME="cicd"
IMAGE_TAG=$IMAGE_TAG



aws ecr get-login-password --region ap-southeast-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 161819723243.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com


docker pull ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${REGION}.amazonaws.com/${IMAGE_REPO_NAME}:"${IMAGE_TAG}"
```

Is there any way to transfer the variable from appspec.yml to .sh file? I asked chatgpt, but I still really confused it